# Running an IF when variable begins with PR

Tags: powershell, user-interface, search, listbox, network-printers

I'm on my first steps with Powershell and I'd like to go into it more.

I'm writing a script that allows the user to connect a network printer to their PC by choosing it from a ListBox.

I have two types of printers. PR stands for printer and SC stands for scanner.

When choosing a PR device, it shows a specific window. Unfortunately the script doesn't understand that by PR* I mean all printers starting with these two letters.

This is my code:

```
$x = $listBox.SelectedItem
if ($x -eq "PR*"){
    $windowDR.ShowDialog()}
```

I appreciate every type of help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the `-like` operator to do what you seek.

```
$x = $listBox.SelectedItem
if ($x -like "PR*"){
    $windowDR.ShowDialog()}
```

> **Matching Operators**
>
> The like operators (-like and -notlike) find elements that match or do not match a specified pattern using wildcard
>   expressions.
>
> The syntax is:
>
> ```
> <string[]> -like <wildcard-expression>
> <string[]> -notlike <wildcard-expression>
> ```
>
> ...
>
> **-like**
>
> Description: Match using the wildcard character (*).

Reference: [MSDocs - About Comparison operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_comparison_operators?view=powershell-7)